# RxJava, Proguard and sun.misc.Unsafe

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-proguard, okhttp

I have problems with `RxJava` (1.1.0) when using `Proguard`. I didn't change RxJava version nor its `.pro` file, but after updating `OkHttp` I couldn't compile using `Proguard` because I had warnings about `sun.misc.Unsafe` not being present.

rxJava.pro

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
public static ** test();
}

-dontwarn  rx.internal.util.unsafe.**
```

After adding the `-dontwarn`, the apk can be compiled, but as soon as I use `RxJava` (with `RxAndroid`'s `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`), it crashes with this stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: it.madonie, PID: 8982
java.lang.InternalError
at rx.d.d.b.y.a(UnsafeAccess.java:103)
at rx.d.d.b.x.<clinit>(SpscArrayQueue.java:39)
at rx.d.a.ag.<init>(OperatorObserveOn.java:94)
at rx.d.a.af.a(OperatorObserveOn.java:64)
at rx.d.a.af.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:44)
at rx.a$2.a(Observable.java:158)
at rx.a$2.call(Observable.java:154)
at rx.a.a(Observable.java:8191)
at rx.a.b(Observable.java:8158)
at rx.a.a(Observable.java:8017)
```

I don't understand why `UnsafeAccess` is crashing, it should just look for `sun.misc.Unsafe` and return `false` when it isn't present.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by adding

```
compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.1.0.0'
```

to my dependencies.