# Android Generated Signed APK causes internal error on launch

Tags: android, apk

This happened recently on my project, when I build the project and launch it on my device, it worked just fine, but when I generate the signed apk and install the apk on my device, java.lang internalError occurred.

I'm sure I have inputted the right password, and use the right .jks file.

What could possibly be the problem here?

Here is the stack trace :

```
ACRA caught a InternalError for com.myApp
                                     java.lang.InternalError
                                         at f.d.d.b.y.a(UnsafeAccess.java:109)
                                         at f.d.d.b.h.<clinit>(MpmcArrayQueue.java:31)
                                         at f.d.d.j.<init>(ObjectPool.java:1143)
                                         at f.d.d.j.<init>(ObjectPool.java:39)
                                         at f.d.d.p.<init>(RxRingBuffer.java:280)
                                         at f.d.d.o.<clinit>(RxRingBuffer.java:280)
                                         at f.j.a(Observable.java:6217)
                                         at com.myApp.mainpage.c.g.s(TopikTrendingVH.java:10026)
                                         at com.myApp.mainpage.c.g.<init>(TopikTrendingVH.java:55)
                                         at com.myApp.mainpage.c.k.a(TrendingPageAdapter.java:162)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.et.b(RecyclerView.java:18482)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.db.a(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.y(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.w(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(CoordinatorLayout.java:11091)
                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1190)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1954)
                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1808)
                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1717)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1954)
                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1808)
                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1717)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15991)
                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2550)
                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1323)
                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6695)
```

Comment: @Karate_Dog rxjava is throwing an UnsafeAccess error and that is probably because of an issue with proguard.

Comment: I would check this out it might be the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810689/rxjava-proguard-and-sun-misc-unsafe

Comment: @srayhunter Exactly what I needed, the problem lies on the proguard rules for RxJava. Thanks